# Passing Class Object to WCF Service c# wp8

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to pass the class object via Post Async Method

```
public async void SAveDetails(clsPickList obj)
{
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        HttpContent content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj));
        content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
        var result = await  client.PostAsync("http://-Port-/-svc file name-/InsertUserDetails", content) ;
        result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        if (result.Content != null)
        {
            var responseContent = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

to

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
    UriTemplate = "InsertUserDetails")]
string InsertUserDetails(Model.clsPickList obj);
```

and Insert object value as follows

```
public string InsertUserDetails(Model.clsPickList obj)
{  
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserName", obj.UserName);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", obj.Password);
}
```

but when I Access th Link via WP8 it returns 404 error.
Since I'm new to WCF ,I really Appreciate anyones Help.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: IF you host the service on your pc and try to access it from your phone it might just be the firewall on your desktop blocking incoming traffic to your service

Comment: What happens when you call "http://-Port-/-svc file name" directly from your browser? Since you get a 404 error; I assume you have a problem either in host URL, or host itself.

Comment: even the browser gives the same Error.. I also have a doubt about the Service .nevertheless how else i pass the class Object..Please could sombody assist..

Comment: Robin B: still it gives the error

Comment: rather than using a svc file i used the webapi (), it works fine now.. Thank you for the help..-RobinB and Jean